# Newb Installing Apache 2.4 & PHP 7 Port 8080

Tags: installation, apache-http-server, php

What's it mean if I can connect to the "It works!" page in Chrome via http://localhost:8080, but not directly using http://localhost, in which event I get "This site can't be reached"? I suppose the question is, how can I access the page without typing in the port number? Shouldn't this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You dont say your Os but this can be on 2 causes, first check if your firewall is blocking port 80, second check your apache ports configuration files, in ubuntu the port configuration is splitted across several files:

In **/etc/apache2/ports** check that there is a 'Listen 80' directive

In **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default** check that there is a VirtualHost *:80 directive

Comment: Sorry, I'm just using Windows. I'm on a Windows machine. Changing the httpd.conf file to Listen on port 80 gives me, "This Site Can't Be Reached" - http://localhost or http://localhost:80.

Comment: I ran a .bat to check what's holding port 80 and 443 and it says "httpd.exe 3848 Services"?

Comment: So if httpd.exe 3848 is Apache2.4 service which is running, how can I just use http://localhost without the colon port number?

Comment: are you running iis? because this sounds like you already have one server running on port 80

Comment: Hey Chico. Nope, I'm not running iis ??

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Comment: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/opening-up-port-80-for-apache-to-use-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost using port 80 so, change your apache config to port 80 not 8080. If you are using ubuntu and apache2, the config file is in /etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf, /etc/apache2/ports.conf.